# Voice Over is not working with custom annotation view iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, annotations, mkmapview

We have implement Voice over in our app. It is working  perfectly for the default Pin annotation of the apple map.

But it is not working with custom annotation view. https://github.com/jpsim/JPSThumbnailAnnotation

Following is some code which is used to add button on annotation view for the click event :

```
- (void)setupDisclosureButton {
    BOOL iOS7 = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0f;
    UIButtonType buttonType = iOS7 ? UIButtonTypeSystem : UIButtonTypeCustom;
    self.disclosureButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:buttonType];
    self.disclosureButton.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    UIImage *disclosureIndicatorImage = [JPSThumbnailAnnotationView disclosureButtonImage];
    [self.disclosureButton setImage:disclosureIndicatorImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.disclosureButton.frame = CGRectMake(kJPSThumbnailAnnotationViewExpandOffset/2.0f + self.frame.size.width/2.0f + 8.0f,
                                         26.5f,
                                         disclosureIndicatorImage.size.width,
                                         disclosureIndicatorImage.size.height);

    [self.disclosureButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapDisclosureButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self addSubview:self.disclosureButton];
}
```

In our app,We are using a third party annotation  Which is internally use a UIButton for the annotation pin.

Voice over is not invoked for this custom annotation view.

Please guide me by provide some clue or sample code.